# Fibonacci shift register pseudo-random number generator

Tags: vb.net, random, fibonacci, bit-shift

I am attempting to get the following code working for a Fibonacci shift register to generate pseudo-random numbers.  Can't seem to get it working, so is(are) there any obvious issues(?)

```
Shared Function Main() As Integer
    Dim start_state As UShort = &HACE1UI ' Any nonzero start state will work.
    Dim lfsr As UShort = start_state
    Dim bit As UInteger
    Dim period As UInteger = 0

    Do While lfsr <> start_state
        ' taps: 16 14 13 11; feedback polynomial: x^16 + x^14 + x^13 + x^11 + 1 
        bit = ((lfsr >> 0) Xor (lfsr >> 2) Xor (lfsr >> 3) Xor (lfsr >> 5)) And 1
        lfsr = (lfsr >> 1) Or (bit << 15)
        period += 1
    Loop 

    Return 0
End Function
```

Last, does "period" need to be divided by a large integer to get U(0,1)'s?

Below is the original C++ code:

```
# include <stdint.h>
int main(void)
{
    uint16_t start_state = 0xACE1u;  /* Any nonzero start state will work. */
    uint16_t lfsr = start_state;
    uint16_t bit;                    /* Must be 16bit to allow bit<<15 later in the code */
    unsigned period = 0;

    do
    {
        /* taps: 16 14 13 11; feedback polynomial: x^16 + x^14 + x^13 + x^11 + 1 */
        bit  = ((lfsr >> 0) ^ (lfsr >> 2) ^ (lfsr >> 3) ^ (lfsr >> 5) ) & 1;
        lfsr =  (lfsr >> 1) | (bit << 15);
        ++period;
    } while (lfsr != start_state);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The loop body will not be entered, because `lfsr = start_state`. Try stepping through the code to see what is going on.

Comment: it was converted from C++ code, which had that statement essentially on the "Loop" line.

Answer (score 2):

As in @dummy's comment,

```
Do While lfsr <> start_state
...
Loop
```

doesn't run because `lfsr = start_state` at the beginning.

The code equivalent to C++

```
do {
...
} while (lfsr != start_state);
```

in VB.NET is

```
Do
...
Loop While lfsr <> start_state
```